# Avoid having a huge collection of ids by calling a DAO.getAll()

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, dao

Instead of returning a `List<Long>` of ids when calling `PersonDao.getAll()` we wanted not to have an entire collection of ids in memory.

Seems like returning a `org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet` and iterate over this rowset would not hold every object in memory.

The only problem here is i cannot cast this row to my entity.

Is there a better way for this?

Generally we want to do a method on every Person in our db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ScrollableResults` to iterate through the result set, and clear the session regularly to dispose of unneeded objects. Example from the Hibernate book:

```
ScrollableResults itemCursor = session.createQuery("from Item").scroll();
int count=0;

while ( itemCursor.next() ) {
  Item item = (Item) itemCursor.get(0);
  modifyItem(item);
  if ( ++count % 100 == 0 ) {
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
  }
}
```

See [the Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-update) for more examples and details.

Comment: great answer! except flushing and clearing i'm afraid of. Do i want this also for other running transactions... StatelessSession looks best for me.

Comment: @Michael Good point, I forgot to mention that this is supposed to be executed in a separate transaction, not to mess up the persistence context. But a StatelessSession can also work.

Comment: éter: Ok but when this is running in a sperate transaction, a session.flush/clear will still affect all transactions in this session, i think.

Comment: @Michael Oops, my bad. I meant **session** indeed, not transaction :-(